# How to listen for a JAX-RS undeployment

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I am running a JAX-RS application that needs to do some clean up once the application is shut down. I installed a shutdown hook for this purpose and it works fine. However, in unit tests, the shut down hook is (of course) not triggered since the JVM is not shut down in between two calls. This I want to fix and only use the shut down hook as a last resort. I imagine, the same would happen if I only undeploy the application from a servlet container without explicitly triggering a shut down. Also, I imagine that I might have created a memory leak in the case the application container continues running with my shut down hook still registered?

**The question**: Is there a possibility to listen for the server / servlet responsible for my JAX-RS application to be destroyed? I was thinking about something like the [`Servlet#destroy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#destroy%28%29) method.

I am looking for something like: `new ResourceConfig().register(new MyShutDownListener())` or something I can do in a `ShutDownBinder`? Any ideas?

Comment: Is the `ServletContextListener.contextDestroyed()` method not good for your case?

Comment: I am starting the application embedded by a `GrizzlyHttpServerFactory` (https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/grizzly2/httpserver/GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.html). I did not find a way to hook myself into that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I found the [`org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.ContainerLifecycleListener`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/index.html) interface. It seems as if this interface found its way into Jersey in v2.3 while my built was using v2.1. I now upgraded Jersey and use it happily. (This is however a Jersey interface, it does not have a sibling in JAX-RS.)

If this is not an option for a future reader of this answer, I found another solution with using [`GrizzlyWebContainerFactory`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/snapshot/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/grizzly2/servlet/GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.html) which allows me to use define my own servlet for starting up the application. This solution was however way more verbose.

Comment: Using this interface finally helped me to tackle the problem described [here](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/What-is-the-proper-way-of-cleaning-up-asynchronous-requests-before-servlet-redeploy-Jersey-Tomcat-td7583818.html) of cancelling an open AsyncResponse in time during application shutdown before one cannot interact with it anymore. All the other possibilities (like `@PreDestroy`, a `ServletContextListener`, or `@Observes @Destroyed( ApplicationScoped.class )`) didn't work.